# Django LAMP Apache mod_wsgi Python changes not taking effect

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, mod-wsgi

I've got my LAMP setup with Ubuntu 20.04.4, Apache, MariaDB, and of course Python. The Django code managed to create some tables for me in the database but I just get 404 when I try to load my form in my browser via URL `http://127.0.0.1/vcm/create_unit`. But it works with the Python dev server at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/vcm/create_unit`.

Edit:
Solved... `sudo systemctl restart apache`

It seems Apache doesn't rerun the python files so modifications don't take effect. Restarting Apache seems to do the job. The Python dev server doesn't suffer from this problem. So I guess while developing the Python dev server is a good option.

The code below seems to be working.

Apache apache2.conf

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so

WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/vcm_project/vcm_project/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonHome /opt/env
WSGIPythonPath /opt/vcm_project

<Directory /opt/vcm_project/vcm_project>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

From TEMPLATES in settings.py I've hardcoded the path to my .html

```py
'DIRS': [ '/opt/vcm_project/vcm/templates/vcm' ],
```

urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('create_unit', views.create_unit, name='create_unit'),
]
```

models.py

```py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Unit(models.Model):
    unit_code = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    unit_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    unit_sector = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    unit_application = models.TextField(max_length=65535)
    unit_url = models.URLField(max_length=255)
    superseded_equivalent = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.unit_name

class Element(models.Model):
    element_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    element_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.element_name
```

forms.py

```py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Unit

class UnitForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Unit
        fields = ('__all__')
```

views.py

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Unit
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the vcm index.")


def create_unit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = UnitForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            form.save()
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = UnitForm()

    return render(request, 'vcm/create_unit.html', {'form': form})
```

My HTML is here
`/opt/vcm_project/vcm/templates/vcm/create_unit.html`

create_unit.html

```py
<form action="{% url 'create_unit' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

admin.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from .models import Unit

admin.site.register(Unit)


from .models import Element

admin.site.register(Element)
```

Comment: Please elaborate which url you're trying to access.

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1/create_unit` or `http://127.0.0.1/vcm/create_unit`

Comment: Since LAMP mentioned I guess you're trying to access page via Apache, so it can be a mistake in Apache config. Please do the `runserver` and try to access Django app directly via `:8000` port (by default). Currently it is unclear which part of setup is broken.

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1/admin/` works. So does `http://127.0.0.1/vcm/` The LAMP setup is good.

Comment: You're on to something though... I'm getting different results from each server